# Changing the description of a MP3 file?

Tags: php

I am currently using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse some MP3 files from another website, and store them onto my own server. However I've noticed that some of them contain a tag which indicates the location they originated from within the comment portion of the [ID3 properties](https://www.google.com/search?q=ID3&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS761US761&oq=ID3&aqs=chrome..69i57.220j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image]

I need to make this website, say my own websites name. However, the only solution that I've found to doing this with PHP is beyond complicated using something called [GETID3.php](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/blob/master/demos/demo.write.php#L69-L101) You can view the github link by clicking the name.

I don't really understand the documentation can someone help me find an easier way of doing this please?

Here's the part of my code that matters, I guess.

```
$mp3title = ''.$thetitle.' - Oursite.com';
file_put_contents($DPATH.'/temp/'.$mp3title.'.mp3',file_get_contents($filepath));
$file = $DPATH.'/temp/'.$mp3title.'.mp3';
```

Comment: So… you're stealing content from another site and you want help making it look like it's your own?

Comment: @Chris please refrain from derailing my question, your comment has literally nothing to do with what I asked which is the issue of updating ID3 data in a proper way.

Comment: I find Chris's point a fair one, frankly.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're not interested in also updating the image of the file, you can look into just using something simple like the default php function [id3_set_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php) however for more complex usages like updating the artwork then you're going to have to use the library you mentioned before.

```
$data = array(
    "title" => "Re:Start",
    "artist" => "Re:\Legion",
    "comment" => "YourWebsiteName.com"
);

$result = id3_set_tag($DPATH.'/temp/'.$mp3title.'.mp3', $data, ID3_V1_0 );
if ($result === true) {
    echo "Tag successfully updated\n";
}
```